# Cant update my database

Tags: java, database, textfield

i cannot update my database using the value from my textfield going to my database i have no exceptions error but nothing happens with it

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    row = table.getSelectedRow();
    int column = table.getColumnCount();

    try {
        Conn();
        System.out.print(table.getValueAt(row,0));
        pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("update customer_tbl set LName = '" + txtLname.getText() + "', FName= '" 
            + txtFname.getText() + "', Address = '" + txtAddress.getText() + "', ContactNumber = '"+txtContact.getText() 
            + "', Age = '" + txtAge+"' WHERE Name_ID = '" + table.getValueAt(row,0) + "'");

        //  st = conn.createStatement();
        // rs = st.executeQuery("UPDATE customer_tbl SET Fname = '"+txtFname.getText()+"' Lname= '"+txtLname.getText()+"', Age = '"+txtAge.getText()+"', Address = '"+txtAddress.getText()+"', ContactNumber = '"+txtContact+"' WHERE Customer_id = '"+ table.getValueAt(row,0)+"'");
        pStmt.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Update success !");

        //FillList();
    }
```

Comment: What is in your `catch(...) {...}` block?

Comment: got an exception sir com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Age' at row 1

Comment: ??? in your question though you state, `" i have no exceptions error..."` and so your statement above, `"got an exception"` is quite confusing to me. Which is it?

Comment: You've recently deleted [your question on isSelectRow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159839/isselectedrow-in-jtable-return-1) without it being answerable and without letting us know what was wrong, then you've asked this question, that doesn't make sense re exception vs. no exception (was it that you were just not catching the exception?).... Please check out the [help] section on [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to improve your future questions so that they can be answered and make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but I got the answer. i am setting `Age = txtAge` not to `txtAge.getText()`